# Accessing global object wcmmode in AEM from a handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js, aem

I can access a component properties from an hbs template for that component like this:

```
{{properties.title}}
```

but I want to access the wcmmode from that (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/global-objects.html) so I can decide to render or not some information in design or edit mode. I now you can access this variable in sightly using:

```
<p data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}">You are in edit mode</p>
<p data-sly-test="${wcmmode.design}">You are in design mode</p>
```

But that does not work on hbs, I tried:

```
<p data-sly-test="{{wcmmode.edit}}">You are in edit mode</p>
<p data-sly-test="{{wcmmode.design}}">You are in design mode</p>
```

That always evaluates as true regardless of the real mode. Any ideas on how to correctly access this?

Answer (score 0):

I found help in the adobe forums, it can be controlled like this:

```
{{#if-wcm-mode mode="<mode1>,<mode2>"}}
    ...
{{else}}
    ...
{{/if-wcm-mode}}
```

"mode" can be compared against a comma separated list of know modes.
Thread where the answer came from:

[Original thread on adobe forums](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__nyhq-i_can_accessacompo.html#forum__nyhq-i_can_accessacompo__1pb1-try_this_if)